# iPhone: Slide photos by finger

Tags: iphone

I want to implement something like Iphone Photo Gallery... How to slide images by finger, and how to do that animation if I want to slide photos by clicking on button ? Thanks...

Comment: Refer to this link : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Three20](http://three20.info/) project, it has a lot of this gallery stuff already implemented and is open source. It has swiping through images implemented. If you want to do it by yourself, [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) would be a good starting point. Have a look at the sample code associated with it.

Comment: I dont want to use Three20, it's takes to many space. I look to UISwipeGestureRecognizer, good idea...but how to make animated switch between images ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `PanGestureRecogniser` on the view you want to slide.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *imgpan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollBarDrag:)];
[imgpan setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[self.svContainer addGestureRecognizer:imgpan];
[imgpan release];
```

Define this & as the pan is happening, slide in the next image...Hope i was clear.